# Why don't tabs open automatically when I reopen my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution

I have an [ASP.NET MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) application solution (.sln). When I close Visual Studio and then reopen it and my solution, my tabs and my navigation structure in the solution explorer do not restore to the way they were.

The solution is big and it takes me a long time to reopen many tabs and open lots of folders in the solution explorer.

Is there an option in VS that would allow me to restore the solution to where it was when I left it?

I've already done "Reset all settings" in the Import and Export Settings Wizard, but it didn't help.

I've also tried booting VS in [/SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) which disables any extensions. No difference.

Searching around I can't see anyone have similar issues.

Comment: "Reset all settings" in the Import and Export Settings Wizard helped me thanks. Open tabs stopped being saved after last November update for VS 2013 for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know the `.suo-File` saves which files are opened. Try to delete this file (VS will generate it new) and make sure that windows-file-permissions are set correct (read, write access).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013, and I solved it by doing this:

- Export my current settings, making sure to UNMARK General Settings > Window Layouts.
- Re-import the settings I just exported, but making sure I left General Settings > Window Layouts MARKED now (so it would overwrite the current Window Layouts with the "clean slate" of the imported settings.

Answer (score 2):

Got this issue also for Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.

How to fix :

First, be sure, that `tools->Project and solutions->General`:'`Reopen documents on solution load`' and '`Restore Solution Explorer project hierarchy state on solution load`' **enabled**

Second, just close VS and `delete .vs folder`, then re-start VS.

Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the Workspace Reloader plugin that Scott Hanselman blogged about?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWorkspaceReloaderAVisualStudioAddInToSaveYourOpenFilesAcrossProjectReloads.aspx

You can install it from here - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6705affd-ca37-4445-9693-f3d680c92f38

Comment: I'm not sure if that extension solves my problem. It's interesting that Scott says "Visual Studio saves all your open files and window positions when you close the IDE and restores them when you open your solution" - mine does nothing of the sort. When I close VS, it doesn't "save" anything.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Not sure if it'll help. But perhaps try resetting your environment settings?

From the Tools Menu, select "Import and Export Settings".
Choose the "Reset all settings" option. 

Then open a few tabs from your solution and then close your solution. Open it back up and see how that goes.